# An old email address is being associated with my Apple ID. How can I remove this?

Tags: icloud, apple-id, find-my-iphone

When I signed up for my first Apple ID, I used a Yahoo email address.  Then when gmail came out, I somehow switched my Apple ID sign on email address to my new gmail.

A few days ago, on a new Apple ID (on a clean install of iOS 13 on an iPhone SE) I used the “friends” feature to add my gmail email address so I could use location sharing between my iPhone 10 and SE .  The gmail address was successfully added, however the email address being shown is the old yahoo email.

I’ve gone through every setting on both iPhones and iCloud and no where is the yahoo email used.  I strongly suspect this is being stored somewhere in Apple’s back end.

Does anyone know where this might be stored and how to fix it?  I’m using some third party software where it’s expecting to get the current email address of the Apple ID, not an old one.

Comment: Do you mean you changed your address on a single Apple ID, or did you set up a second, new ID? If the latter, then anything you set up on the initial ID still belongs to that ID & is not transferrable.